# Django rest framework "Like" functionality

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

in django, I want to write a function that deletes the likes if the current user has liked that post before and if so, how can I do this.

This is my models.py

```
class Like(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_by.username
```

This is my serializers.py

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    post = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    post_id = serializers.IntegerField()
  

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('__all__')
```

This is my views.py

```
    class LikesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Like.objects.all()
        serializer_class = LikeSerializer
        
        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include

from .views import (
    PostView,
    PostView_View,
    LikesView,
    CommentView
)
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('likes', LikesView)
router.register('post', PostView)
router.register('comment', CommentView)

urlpatterns = [

] + router.urls
```

I try that but still nor working

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    post = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    post_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('__all__')

    def post(self, request, post_id):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        if Like.objects.filter(post=post, 
       created_by=request.user).exists():
            Like.objects.filter(post=post, created_by=request.user).delete()
        else:
            Like.objects.create(post=post, created_by=request.user)
```

Comment: And what is an error you are solving?

Answer (score 0):

For this action, you can override the serializer's save method. First, get an object from a table, and if it exists, delete it

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: I edited but still not working